# Can I use UWP toast notification control in a portable class library?

Tags: c#, uwp

My question is exactly that, I have a PCL '.dll' which has been integrated with a voip system I want to make the most out of using the toast notifications that universal windows supplies to relay data to the user.

Can I have a refrence to the UWP controls in a 'Portable Class Library' which is ran by another running service ??

Comment: No, you can't - because then it wouldn't be a portable class library.

Comment: Well, technically you can - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx - by opting in to the UWP-specific references, but your assembly would not be portable to other platforms that lack that WinRT call. You're better-off using traditional platform-specific code techniques.

Comment: Ok, what if I didnt reference uwp from my pcl. If I had universal windows app running simultaniously with the pcl I could have them communicate over [NamedNetPipeBindings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752247(v=vs.110).aspx) right. so when a event is hit in my PCL can i call the control in my UWP app to push the notification control.